# How to set prefetch count to 1 for amqplib for nodejs

Tags: node-amqp

How do i set the prefetch count to one for amqplib in nodejs?
[link to Lib on git](https://github.com/squaremo/amqp.node)

The desired result is that the consumer is only taking one message from the queue process it and when done take a new message. I have a setup where some messages takes long time to process and others take very short time. Hence i do not just want to share the messages equally on all consumers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used ch.prefetch(1); after asserting the queue with a task and before binding the queue to an exchange.

Answer (score 0):

```
channel.prefetch(1);
```

[You can view the docs here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html#:%7E:text=Fair%20dispatch) for reference